# Prior function definition makes 'let' binding fail

Tags: ocaml

The following code does not work:

```ml
let get_json file =
    try
        Yojson.Basic.from_file file
    with
        | Sys_error message when message = (file ^ ": No such file or directory") ->
                Printf.printf "File named '%s' not found\n" file ; exit 0

let json = 10 in let y = 1 + json in Printf.printf "%d %d" json y
```

It gives the following error `Error: Syntax error` on the `in` keyword.

The following code does work:

```ml
let json = 10 in let y = 1 + json in Printf.printf "%d %d" json y

let get_json file =
    try
        Yojson.Basic.from_file file
    with
        | Sys_error message when message = (file ^ ": No such file or directory") ->
                Printf.printf "File named '%s' not found\n" file ; exit 0
```

This means the function definition makes the following 'let' binding fail.

I compile my program like this:

```
EXECUTABLE = ft_turing
COMPILER = ocamlc
COMPILER_OPT = ocamlopt
SRCDIR = ./src
SRCSFILES = main.ml
SRCS = $(addprefix $(SRCDIR)/,$(SRCSFILES))
OBJECTS = $(SRCS:.ml=.cmo)
OBJECTS_OPT = $(SRCS:.ml=.cmx)

all: $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    ocamlfind $(COMPILER) -o $@ -linkpkg -package yojson $^

%.cmo: %.ml
    ocamlfind $(COMPILER) -c -package yojson $<
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root issue is that

```
let json = 10 in let y = 1 + json in Printf.printf "%d %d" json y
```

is not an definition but an expression. Thus your first example reads as:

```
let get_json file =
    try
        Yojson.Basic.from_file file
    with
        | Sys_error message when message = (file ^ ": No such file or directory") ->
     Printf.printf "File named '%s' not found\n" file ;
    exit 0 (let json = 10 in let y = 1 + json in Printf.printf "%d %d" json y)
```

which is an error since the `exit` function only expects one argument (white space are never significant in OCaml (outside of separating word)).

Contrarily, your second example is a toplevel expression followed by a let-definition that is equivalent to

```
1 + 1
let x = 0
```

which works fine.
To make your first example works, you can separate the toplevel expression from a previous definition with `;;`:

```ml
let get_json file =
    try
        Yojson.Basic.from_file file
    with
        | Sys_error message when message = (file ^ ": No such file or directory") ->
     Printf.printf "File named '%s' not found\n" file ;
    exit 0
;; let json = 10 in let y = 1 + json in Printf.printf "%d %d" json y
```

or avoid toplevel expressions altogether with:

```ml
let get_json file =
    try
        Yojson.Basic.from_file file
    with
        | Sys_error message when message = (file ^ ": No such file or directory") ->
     Printf.printf "File named '%s' not found\n" file ;
    exit 0
let () =
  let json = 10 in
  let y = 1 + json in
  Printf.printf "%d %d" json y
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer you are right. But can you explain me why `let json = 10` is not a definition while `let () = json = 10` is. What does `let () =` mean?

Comment: `let json = 10` is a definition. It is `let json = 10 in 1 + json` which is not a definition: the name `json` introduced by `let json = ... in  1 + json` is local to the expression `1+json`. Thus the whole sentence `let ... = ... in ... ` is always an expression and never a definition. `let () = ... ` is a definition like any other, it is just a definition that doesn't bind any part of its body while still enforcing that the type of the body is `unit`?

Answer (score 0):

Both `let` are not equivalent. The first one is creates a global variable. The second one is part of an expression.

Then your whole script is like:

```ml
let get_json file =
   an_expression

an_other_expression
```

The logical meaning should be (at the syntax level) to call the function `an_expression` with the argument `an_other_expression`.

Then you should restructure the program like:

```ml
let get_json file =
   an_expression

let () = 
   let json = 10 in an_other_expression
```

You can also separate let bindings from expressions with `;;`.

(Note: I find it curious that there is a syntax error on the `in`, I would think of the other issue I have expressed. We can provoke the issue I was thinking writing `(let json = 10 in ...)` with parenthesis).